# 500 OOPS: chroot on vsftpd login

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I'm aware this question has been asked *a lot* in the past, but my problem seems to be a bit different. I'm using `vsftpd` on my CentOS 7 server and I have specified `chroot_local_user` to `YES` in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`. The FTP user is called `user`, and their home directory is `/home/user`. When I try to log in, I get this:

```
500 OOPS: chroot
Login failed.
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

I've been searching for a solution, but people seem to only get `refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()`, not this. I have tried two things:

1.Remove *all* write permissions on `/home/user`:

```
[user@vps226220 ~]$ ls -al /home | grep user
dr-x------.  4 user      user      4096 Dec 12 00:56 user
```

2.Add `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`, then `sudo systemctl restart vsftpd`.

In both cases nothing changed, I still get the same error. Note that if I set `chroot_local_user=NO`, it works fine, but of course this isn't an acceptable configuration for me.

My `vsftpd` version is 3.0.2, so I believe it should support `allow_writable_chroot`.

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: For some reason, `chroot()` syscall failed inside vsftpd subprocess. Or it will stop claims only when directory will be owned by root. Use `strace` to start master process and find out why.

Comment: According to the some docs, the option name you might want is `allow_writeable_chroot` (note the _e_ in "writeable"), not `allow_writable_chroot`?

Comment: *NOTE* that "allow_writable_chroot" does **not** work in the Vanilla vsftpd that comes with CentOS/Redhat 7. You need to install a third-party vsftpd for that.

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of CentOS/RHEL, the `ftp_home_dir` option was removed; hence, you can use `ftpd_full_access`. I'm not fully aware of the security implications but this is how I got it to work:

```
 # setsebool -P ftpd_full_access on
```

links:

[ftp_home_dir is missing in RHEL 7.3](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2857381)

[Is it the end for FTP? “ftp_home_dir” Issue](http://www.johnyoung.tech/is-it-the-end-for-ftp/)

Answer (score 3):

It's a SELinux question.

```
# setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1
```

Comment: Try explaining the functionality of the suggested command rather than just blurting it out. That way, it would help others, looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have a situation where a pre-programmed Robot User on Host A needs to PUSH files to a pre-programmed location on Host B. There should be little concern that the Robot User will attempt to push/pull files to/from any other location.

Further, we are disinclined to change the code to accommodate a pre-programmed writable sub-directory that the process would need to "cd" to.

So we solved this issue by setting the configuration parameter "chroot_local_user" to "NO".

Answer (score 0):

After getting this error; I made all things which you mentioned, but I still had erorrs. I had checked logs and then applied these steps to solve my problem:

1. `ausearch -c 'vsftpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-vsftpd`
2. `semodule -i my-vsftpd.pp`

After 2nd command, my-vsftpd.pp  my-vsftpd.te files has been created my ftp host's file directory which was created for ftp host like below:

```
sudo adduser testuser
sudo passwd testuser
echo "testuser" | sudo tee –a /etc/vsftpd/user_list   (for conf file )   
sudo mkdir –p /home/testuser/ftp/upload
sudo chmod 777 /home/testuser/ftp
sudo chmod 777 /home/testuser/ftp/upload
sudo mkdir –p /home/testuser/ftp/upload
```

Comment: It would be great if you could describe what particular commands are doing. It will help understand others what exactly happens.